# how can you use the summon command or setblock command with players cordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

i was trying to make a fake skeleton and i came in the problem he coudnt shoot arrows because the player runs away i want to summon them next to the player or make blocks right behind the player so can you help me by saying how to do so

Comment: Hi sheep_flyer: It might help if you list what you've tried, or why this isn't working - for instance, you say "he can't shoot arrows because the player runs away". From the next line, I have to guess that you want the arrows to hit the player, but they currently don't?

Answer (score 0):

To execute commands around a specific target use the execute command.

```
/execute <Target> <X> <Y> <Z> <Command>
```

In this case

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ summon Skeleton
```

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute at <target> run <command>`